# PHP Contact Form - Posting to a send script, on validation fail, return to contact form & page anchor

Tags: php, html, forms, anchor

my first post so be gentle...
I have a PHP contact form where on a php page (contact.php)

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="send.php">
```

On clicking the send button the data goes to the send.php script to be validated. If passes validation, the user views a sent.html page where the message "Your Message Has Been Sent - Thank You" is displayed

```
$message = "Your Message Has Been Sent - Thank You";
include "sent.html";
```

However if validation fails, for example, if a field is left blank the  validation fails the send & the $message is displayed on the within the form, back on the on the contact.php...

```
if ((!$fname) OR (!$lname) OR (!$email) OR (!$enquiry))
{
$message = "ERROR: ALL FEILDS MARKED * MUST BE COMPLETED";
include "contact.php";
exit();
```

The message is displayed on the contact.php page form using:

```
<?php 
    print "$message";
?>
```

This is operational, but the form is halfway down the page and the user has to scroll down to view the failed sending of the message, which could be missed, and views poorly... How can I ensure that on failed validation the contact.php page is displayed with the form at the top of the page? Can I apply an anchor, or a method or returning to the form id? Thanks in advance.

Update:
Sorry I should have said, there is other validation in the send.php script that the forms action=send.php goes to which does not allow web addresses, on each field & validates email field etc so i guess I was hoping that i could amend the code below to redirect to an anchor via the forms ID, on the contact.php page:

```
if ((!$fname) OR (!$lname) OR (!$email) OR (!$enquiry))
{
$message = "ERROR: ALL FEILDS MARKED * MUST BE COMPLETED";
include "contact.php";
exit();
}
```

UPDATE: Thank you all for your time & comments, it's really appreciated. I ended up creating a new page which held the form only, and amended the send.php to show the following:

```
if ((!$fname) OR (!$lname) OR (!$email) OR (!$enquiry))
{
$message = "ERROR: ALL FEILDS MARKED * MUST BE COMPLETED";
include "newform.php";
exit();
}
```

Not the best I know, but works all the same, I figured that if the user wanted to fill in the form, at least they were faced with the form with the error message displayed, easy to view. I did try to use

```
onsubmit="document.location.href='http://fullurl/contact.php#formtop'"
```

This had partial success as toy could see the form focus on the anchor for a slit second before scrolling to the top of the page, I guess the onsubmit worked on till sent to the send.php script blew that out of the water. 
@ Sergey: The sent.html was a lazy way of letting the user know the message was was sent, this html page does not show the form, as clearing the form, post successful validation was not known to me... I'm a front end designer, not a coder like you guys.
Cheers
Gaz

Comment: Of course you can use an anchor in your form’s `action` to refer to an element via its `id`.

Comment: Move your `IF` statement that catches a failed validation higher in the page. That will allow you to call `contact.php` earlier instead of later therefore showing up at the top of the page.

Comment: It's a bit hard to offer a good solution without knowing the structure of your files (namely, contact.php and send.php, but sent.html is also of a bit of interest). If you could publish them somewhere in their entirety (with sensitive data removed, of course), it would help us greatly to make useful suggestions.